# C# strange Method call using pointer?

Tags: c#, pointers, com

I have found a code that does a directx com import. But i don t understand it and it also does not work in my code.

It is this code:

```
internal unsafe Result GetCapabilities(out BufferCapabilities dSBufferCapsRef)
{
    BufferCapabilities.__Native native = BufferCapabilities.__NewNative();
    Result result = (Result) **(((IntPtr*) base._nativePointer))[(int) (((IntPtr) 3) * sizeof(void*))](base._nativePointer, (IntPtr) &native);
    dSBufferCapsRef = new BufferCapabilities();
    dSBufferCapsRef.__MarshalFrom(ref native);
    result.CheckError();
    return result;
}
```

The strange Line is Line Two in the method. The Result result = ....
_nativePointer is declared like this:

```
protected unsafe void* _nativePointer;
```

So my answer how is it possible to call a member of the cominterface the pointer is refering to. How can I call this: (base._nativePointer, (IntPtr) &native).
It is a member of the Interface the pointer _nativePointer is pointing to.

I know that i am a bit confusing but I hope you understand my question.

Comment: It looks like it is directly calling the 4th function of a COM interface.  Likely to be IDirectSoundBuffer8::GetCaps().  You don't want to maintain this code, throw it away.

Answer (score 1):

From [MSDN - Pointer Types (C# Programming Guide](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/y31yhkeb.aspx):

> `*` Performs pointer indirection.
>
> `->` Accesses a member of a struct through a pointer.

You would use them as follows:

`pointer->field`
or
`(*pointer).field`

**Note:** (Also from [MSDN - Pointer Types (C# Programming Guide](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/y31yhkeb.aspx)):

> You cannot apply the indirection operator to a pointer of type void*.
>   However, you can use a cast to convert a void pointer to any other
>   pointer type, and vice versa.

It looks like there is one main line that is causing confusion.  I'll try ot break it down:

```
Result result = (Result) **(((IntPtr*) base._nativePointer))[(int) (((IntPtr) 3) * sizeof(void*))](base._nativePointer, (IntPtr) &native);
```

The first part is fairly self-explanatory: `Result result = (Result)...`

Then we have `**(((IntPtr*) base._nativePointer))`, which appears to be casting base._nativePointer to an IntPtr*, and then dereferecning it twice.  That means that it must point to another pointer.  We dereference once to get the pointed-to pointer, and then again to get that pointer's value.  We'll call this `X`.

The next portion is `[(int) (((IntPtr) 3) * sizeof(void*))]`.  It gets the size of a void pointer, and then multiplies it by 3 (don't ask me why it's being cast as an IntPtr first).  Then it uses that value to index X.  It is finding the index of X that is 3 void*'s from it's beginning.

The last portion is `(base._nativePointer, (IntPtr) &native)`.  This tells me that the value at `X[3 void's]` (pseudocode for above) is a function and we're calling it.

Overall, the line of code calls a function stored in (or near?) the pointer pointed to by `base._nativePointer`.  The function is passed the paramters `base._nativePointer` and `&native` (cast to an IntPtr), and returns a `Result`.

Comment: But how does that code i posted works?
Because what i don t understand is how that codes is able access the  member without a membername. It is accessed by the index that is in the [] and after that a method is called with the paramter in the ()

Comment: ok i see you edited your answer. thanks a lot. but i can t call the function. how can i call that function?

Comment: do i have to cast it into a delegate or what?

Comment: Did you write up `GetCapabilities`, or was it autogenerated?  What function are you trying to call?  If you wrote the code that is in that function, and it is not working, try casting it to a delegate.